# How to add prev and next button in slide show

Tags: javascript

I just made this program for slide show it is working well but i want to use previous and next buttons in the slide show and i don't have any idea how to do that so i put this here please help for the same

```
 var image1=new Image()
  image1.src="slide/23.jpg"
  var image2=new Image()
  image2.src="slide/7.jpg"
  var image3=new Image()
  image3.src="slide/4.jpg"
  var image4=new Image()
  image4.src="slide/5.jpg"
  var image5=new Image()
  image5.src="slide/6.jpg"    

  </script> 
  <img id="myImg"src="slide/2.jpg" name="img" width="1000" height="250"/>  



<script>

  var step=1

  function slideImages(){

  if (!document.images)

   return

  document.images.img.src=eval("image"+step+".src")

  if (step<5)

  step++

 else

step=1

 setTimeout("slideImages()",3000)

 }

slideImages()

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to abstract away some code so it can be easily reused in your functions:

```
// Dealing with the counter:
var step;
var steps = 5;

function increment() {
  s = (s + 1) % steps;
}

function decrement() { 
  s--; 
  if (s<0) s = steps-1;
}


// Dealing with the slide show:
function show() {
  document.images.img.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
}

function next() {
  increment();
  show();
}

function prev() {
  decrement();
  show();
}

// Automatic sliding:
window.setInterval(next, 3000);
```

Also, i would reconsider your approach to storing images:

```
function createImgBySource(src){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  return img;
}

var images = [
  createImgBySource('slide/23.jpg'),
  createImgBySource('slide/7.jpg'),
  createImgBySource('slide/4.jpg'),
  createImgBySource('slide/5.jpg'),
  createImgBySource('slide/6.jpg')
];
```

Now you can change the increment and decrement functions to use images.length instead of steps, so you can add more images without having to alter other variables. Also, your show() function should look like this (getting rid of the nasty eval):

```
function show() {
  document.images.img.src = images[step];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
var ss = new TINY.fader.init("ss", {
    id: "slides", // ID of the slideshow list container
    position: 0, // index where the slideshow should start
    auto: 0, // automatic advance in seconds, set to 0 to disable auto advance
    resume: true, // boolean if the slideshow should resume after interruption
    navid: "pagination", // ID of the slide nav list
    activeClass: "current", // active class for the nav relating to current slide
    pauseHover: true, // boolean if the slideshow should pause on slide hover
    navEvent: "click", // click or mouseover nav event toggle
    duration: .25 // duration of the JavaScript transition in seconds, else the CSS controls the duration, set to 0 to disable fading
});
```

got from [Here](https://www.scriptiny.com/2012/08/javascript-slideshow-code-css3/) also here is a sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamacatperson/hHnX5/)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using something like [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are best putting all of your images into an array and then looking over it. I am assuming that the image tag with the ID 'myImg' is the one that you want to update, as such you should use `document.getElementByID('myImg')` and not `document.images.img.src=eval("image"+step+".src")` -- `eval` should also be avoided as the performance is poor and it can be dangerous.

Put this as the end of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var step = 0;

    var images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5];  
    var image = document.getElementByID('myImg');

    var slideImages = function() {
        image.src = images[step].src;
        step++;
        if (step == images.length){
            step == 0;
        }
        setTimeout("slideImages()", 3000);
    };

  slideImages()
})();
</script>
```